# What text editors does --dev reload with work

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm following [Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html) to use the `--dev all` parameter when I run `odoo-bin`, in order to have Python models get updated when I change the source code without me having to restart the server.  According to the documentation, the `reload` flag (which is part of `all`) doesn't work with some text editors.  I've been using Sublime Text, and that doesn't seem to work because my model changes don't take effect until I restart the server.  Is there a good, commonly used text editor which does work with the `reload` parameter, or is there a list of text editors which work with it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're running Odoo from the command line via a standard `./odoo-bin --dev reload` command then you should not have any issues as long as you have the lib dependencies setup.

Make sure to monitor your log for errors. It requires the `watchdog` library to be installed via `pip install watchdog`. Take a look at (currently line 943) of the core files https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/service/server.py to see how dev reload works:

```py
def start(preload=None, stop=False):

    ...

    watcher = None
    if 'reload' in config['dev_mode']:
        if watchdog:
            watcher = FSWatcher()
            watcher.start()
        else:
            _logger.warning("'watchdog' module not installed. Code autoreload feature is disabled")
    if 'werkzeug' in config['dev_mode']:
        server.app = DebuggedApplication(server.app, evalex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but after doing a quick search on the text editor that I have been primarily using ([Atom](https://atom.io/) developed by GitHub), I believe it may have what you're looking for.

Have fun with your future endeavors. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I downloaded Atom and tried it, but I still have to restart the server manually for the .pyc file to be recompiled.  I should note that I'm using Windows.  Does the `--dev reload` feature not work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Since odoo uses werkzeug server,you can just use the command line argument to start the server, and everything will be taken care by the server.

./openerp-server --auto-reload

this will restart the server whenever .py file is modified.